# flask/bin/pip install flask==0.9 results in 'no such file or directory'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to follow the guide posted here http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world  and I'm on the step that says install flask and extensions by entering the following commands, one after another:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask==0.9
flask/bin/pip install flask-login
flask/bin/pip install flask-openid
flask/bin/pip install flask-mail
```

ect.

When I enter the first command in terminal, I get "/Users/test/Python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".

No idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a virtualenv? If you are not, I highly recommend that you should.

You can checkout: [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) Also, to make things a bit easier you can also use virtualenvwrapper: [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org).

That being said if you have pip installed on your machine, your should only run  'pip install flask==0.9', etc. You do not need the flask/bin part of the cmd as the tutorial says.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to be working.  I assume I am using virtualenv because I have a file called virtualenv.py and virtualenv.pyc in my project folder now after running the steps in that tutorial.  How do I check that for sure?

Comment: @Ptrkcon: The author of the tutorial assumes that the user is not going to be activating the virtualenv. If someone is following the tutorial step by step, they DO need to type out the full `flask/bin/pip` unless they decide to activate the virtualenv (which the tutorial does not show how to do).