# Running Python Script to LocalHost from Linux Terminal

Tags: python, linux, flask

I am working through Miguel Grinberg's [Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and am unable to run the basic Hello World Flask app in Local Host:

run.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

I am running the following in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
chmod a+x run.py
./run.py
```

Which is generating the following:

```
bash: ./run.py: flask/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have not created yet the virtual environment called "flask" (explained under the *Installing Flask* section), therefore the shebang line fails. I ran it without and with the virtenv and it works.

Check this topic to see if it helps: [flask/bin/pip install flask==0.9 results in 'no such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478030/flask-bin-pip-install-flask-0-9-results-in-no-such-file-or-directory/18478286#18478286).